# Changing setting via api in gmail?

Tags: api, gmail

Is it possible to change gmail settings , create filter etc via some API ? I have searched through the internet and can find an api for gmail contacts and google calendar , but none for gmail settings etc ?
Is such a thing possible ?

Comment: [Maybe this](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html). That page also has examples of filter creation.

Comment: Nice! I was wondering about this too! Thanks for asking this question a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the [e-mail settings API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html) is only applicable for Google Apps for Business or Education accounts (http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60228).

Have you found a way to change these settings - such as creating a filter - for gmail and free google app user accounts?